# Why are none of the changes I made to my project being made? Tomcat server with Docker database

Tags: mysql, docker, jsp, tomcat, docker-compose

I am running tomcat locally and a mysql database in Docker and I have made changes to my .jsp files yet none of these changes are reflected in the website when I run it. I have tried rebuilding the artifacts and even manually creating them again yet the original website remains with no changes. I even tried to run everything through docker with docker-compose and the same thing happens, even when I remove all the images and rebuild the artifacts. I've been going in circles for days trying to fix it with no luck.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the tomcat?

Comment: yes. Tried restarting everything completely with 0 luck @Spectric